# Java Threads yield method query

Tags: java, multithreading

**I am practising threads, I used yield(), iam expecting output as below: (BUT not getting as expected)**

```
One1
Two1
One2
Two2
One3
Two3
.
.
.
.
```

**Whats wrong in my below code?**

```
public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyThread myThread1 = new MyThread("One");
        MyThread myThread2 = new MyThread("Two");

        /*Thread t1 = new Thread(myThread1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(myThread2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();*/


        myThread1.start();
        myThread2.start();
    }
}


class MyThread extends Thread {

    private String name; 

    public MyThread(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run(){

        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++) {
            System.out.println(name+i);
            yield();
        }
    }
}
```

**and also I would like to know does commented statements correct to use or not? I mean below:**

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(myThread1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(myThread2);

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Waiting for your replies..

Comment: What are you getting instead of the expected output?

Comment: `yield` should be used as a testing tool instead of a logical.

Comment: 'I am practising threads, I used yield()' - FAIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yield()` method clearly states in its javadoc that it is

> A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield
>   its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this
>   hint.

As such, you can't always expect execution to pass to another thread. There is no guarantee.

Also, in your question *does commented statements correct to use or not*, no, it won't change anything. The `Thread` constructor accepts a `Runnable` argument on which it will eventually execute the `run()` method. The `Thread` class `implements Runnable` and is therefore a valid argument, but it has the same effect as if you had started the `Thread` itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you `extend thread`, you do it the way you have.  If you `implements Runnable`, you do it the commented way.  Either way is fine.

Note that `yield` is really just a recommendation, so the order of your output is not determined.  You need to use locks or another technique if you want it to always be that certain way.

Answer (score 0):

[Thread#yield](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield) states that

> Causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and allow other threads to execute.

So you won't get expected output here. 
If you want expected output use `wait()` and `notify()` methods with proper synchronization.
`I would like to know does commented statements correct to use or not?`
Yes this is 100% valid java syntax.